# Fusion tables authentication php - daily limit exceeded

Tags: php, google-fusion-tables

From this snippet of code using the Oauth2 access_token:

```
$acsToken = json_decode($client->getAccessToken())->{'access_token'};
$arrHeader = array('Content-Type'=>'application/json', 'Authorization'=>'Bearer '.$acsToken);

$ch = curl_init( 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT%20UserID%20FROM%201DGQPfPkjgcNVUc3ndplxNBlET9TlwoVcQw5_jVA');
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $arrHeader);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec( $ch );

if($response === false){
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo "<br /> response: ".$response; 
}
```

This is what is returned.

response: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg", "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded. Please sign up", "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console" } ], "code": 403, "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded. Please sign up" } }

According to the api Console I have had 50 requests in the past 28 days.  The maximum limit for fusion tables is 25,000 per day.  so I shouldn't be over the limit.

I have not use cURL before.  Is my cURL request malformed?

Comment: if I remember correct, this is because the first request runs into wrong credentials and addtional requests go into that 403 error. Try adding ?key={MY_API_KEY}" to request url

Comment: I added the key.  Received a different error.  response: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "required", "message": "Login Required" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Login Required" } }    Can anyone post a simple example which you know works.  Thanks.

Comment: I just saw a javascript example and the 'scope' is set to scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables'.  I do not set this anywhere in my code.  Does this need to be set?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your API key as a second parameter called `key` to your request.

`https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=<query>&key=<your API key>`

You can find your API key on the [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) on the tab "API Access".